What alien races and named characters are depicted in the scenes from X-Men '97 showing the Shi'ar Empire?
In X-Men '97 (Season 1, Episode 6, "Lifedeath - Part 2"), we see a diverse array of alien races depicted in the scenes set on the Shi'ar throneworld. While some characters looked like typical members of the Shi'ar race, others had unique appearances that caught my eye, making me wonder if they were named characters or representatives of specific races or species.
Here are the relevant screencaps:

In this shot, you can see a character in the center who looks like a human, surrounded by a diverse group of aliens. There are some massive, giant-like beings, green-skinned humanoids, a dark brown-skinned humanoid, and a blue-skinned figure wearing a hood. 

Here, we have four Shi'ar characters. I believe the one on the right is Araki, but I'm drawing a blank on the identities of the other three. 

There's a green-skinned humanoid, and the character I'm most curious about is the four-eyed humanoid with that fluffy green ball creature on their shoulder. There's also a humanoid with an "eye" marking on their forehead and a pointy-eared elf-looking person with a green hood. 

A mix of Shi'ar and non-Shi'ar characters

Green-skinned humanoid (from the scene set in Ronan's ship)
Who are the named characters in these scenes? And for the unnamed ones, what races or species do they belong to? 
